# Limit for nested function calls in C (C99)

Tags: c, c99

Is there a limit in nested calls of functions according to C99?

Example:

```
result = fn1( fn2( fn3( ... fnN(parN1, parN2) ... ), par2), par1);
```

*NOTE: this code is definitely not a good practice because hard to manage; however, this code is generated automatically from a model, so manageability issues does not apply.*

Comment: If you're nesting calls so much that you start worry about limits, then you're not doing it right. Code like that will be unreadable and unmaintainable. Don't even think about writing code like that.

Comment: I'm not writing code. It is some code generated automatically.

Comment: I guess you are limited only by the stack size.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs The function calls aren't really nested but in sequence.

Comment: @Gerhardh If you look into assembly you will see all the registers are being pushed to the stack, and popped after execution is done. Now multiply these few registers by 10k and you *might* hit the limit. As an example, I currently work with the embedded application with stack of 4k.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs There is no reason why the compiler should push more than the 2 parameters for each call on the stack. And the next function is only called after the previous has returned. We are not talking about recursively nesting functions calls but just write a function into parameter list. `par1` doesn't need to be pushed before `fn2` has returned. Very flat stack usage.

Comment: @Gerhardh You are right. Those are not nested calls, and my statement is not applicable to this particular scenario. I need a coffee.

Comment: @Gerhardh: There is reason to push more registers. A routine needs to save the values of all registers it modifies that the ABI says must be preserved across function calls.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right. But my point was that we don't need to care about the nesting. Whatever needs to be stored due to ABI requirements, needs to be stored only for 1 level of function call. Optionally whatever is called within those functions, but this is not related to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no limit.

As a example, this is a C snippet:

```
int func1(int a){return a;}
int func2(int a){return a;}
int func3(int a){return a;}

void main()
{
func1(func2(func3(16)));
}
```

The corresponding assembly code is:

```
0000000000000024 <main>:
  24:   55                      push   %rbp
  25:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  28:   bf 10 00 00 00          mov    $0x10,%edi
  2d:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  32 <main+0xe>
  32:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  34:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  39 <main+0x15>
  39:   89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
  3b:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  40 <main+0x1c>
  40:   90                      nop
  41:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  42:   c3                      retq
```

The `%edi` register stores the result of each function and the `%eax` register stores the argument. As you can see, there are three `callq` instructions which correspond to three function calls. In other words, these nested functions are called one by one. There is no need to worry about the stack.

---

As mentioned in comments, compiler may crash when the code nests too deep.
I write a simple Python script to test this.

```
nest = 64000

funcs=""
call=""

for i in range(1, nest+1):
    funcs += "int func%d(int a){return a;}\n" %i
    call += "func%d(" %i

call += str(1) # parameter
call += ")" * nest + ";" # right parenthesis

content = '''
%s
void main()
{
%s
}
''' %(funcs, call)

with open("test.c", "w") as fd:
    fd.write(content)
```

`nest = 64000` is OK, but `640000` will cause `gcc-5.real: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault (program cc1)`.

Comment: Not at program runtime, but you could run out of memory (or more likely fill up some data structure) at compiletime. The compiler does not need to support arbitrary nesting.

Comment: @DanielH You are right. GCC may terminate because of a large number of nested functions.

Comment: The limit may be system-dependent, but as long as most systems can get even 6400 I wouldn't expect a problem in practice.

Answer (score 8):

There is not directly a limitation, but a compiler is only required to allow some minimum limits for various categories:

From the [C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.1):

> 5.2.4.1 Translation limits
>   1 The implementation shall be able to translate and execute at least one program that contains at least one instance of every one of the following limits: <sup>18)</sup>
>
> ...
>
> - 63 nesting levels of parenthesized expressions within a full expression
>
> ...
>
> - 4095 characters in a logical source line
>
> <sup>18)</sup> Implementations should avoid imposing fixed translation limits whenever possible

Comment: Note that most implementations do follow footnote 18 here, and I doubt you'll find a commonly-used compiler which has either limit that low.

Answer (score 1):

No. Since these functions are executed one by one, there is no issue.

```
int res;
res = fnN(parN1, parN2);
....
res = fn2(res, par2);
res = fn1(res, par1);
```

The execution is linear with previous result being used for next function call.

Edit: As explained in comments, there might be a problem with parser and/or compiler to deal with such ugly code.

Comment: But the compiler itself could run out of space, in the parser or anywhere that a too-deep AST is manipulated recursively

Comment: There aren't any particular runtime limits, but there can be compiletime limits. In practice, it might be more difficult than it's worth to try to make the code generation stick to 4095-character lines and 63-deep parentheses, but you should at least be aware of the limits.

Answer (score 1):

If this is not a purely theoretical question, the answer is probably "Try to rewrite your code so you don't need to do that, because the limit is more than enough for most sane use cases". If this is purely theoretical, or you really do need to worry about this limit and can't just rewrite, read on.

---

Section 5.2.4 of the C11 standard ([latest draft, which is freely available and almost identical](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)) specifies various limits on what implementations are *required* to support. If I'm reading that right, you can go up to 63 levels of nesting.

However, implementations are *allowed* to support more, and *in practice* they probably do. I had trouble finding the appropriate documentation for GCC (the closest I found was for expressions in the preprocessor), but I expect it doesn't have a hard limit except for system resources when compiling.